# Factors (the data structure) in R

Tags: r, data-structures

I am teaching myself R using a textbook written by Richard Cotton and have gotten to the chapter on factors. The book says that  for

```r
heights <- data.frame(height_cm = c(153, 181, 150, 172, 165, 149, 174, 169, 198, 163),
                      gender = c("female", "male", "female", "male", "male", 
                                 "female", "female", "male", "male", "female"))
```

`heights$gender` is a factor but whenever I call `class(heights$gender)` it returns `"character"`. My question is: why is it a character vector instead of a factor like the textbook says it should be?

Comment: By default it is `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `R 4.0-`

Comment: does that mean i have to go through this whole section with as.factor(heights$gender)?

Comment: simply add `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` to `data.frame`

Comment: Or get a new textbook, written since R 4.0.0 was released in April.

Comment: Though in most cases factors cause more issues than not using them

Comment: Or use R version 3.x to match the textbook.

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot more sense.